# A word for "government by murderers"

Tags: single-word-requests, government

Is there a word that describes government by murderers (or just criminals in general) similar to [***kleptocracy***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kleptocracy) being a government of thieves?  I'm looking for something that contains more of this sense than either ***despotism*** or ***tyranny***, but would not necessarily be as extreme as a ***democidal*** regime of the order of Idi Amin's or that of the Khmer Rouge. I recently heard such a situation described as a "Mafia state", but is there a more appropriate one-word alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across **kakistocracy** (or cacistocracy, see also [kakocracy/cacocracy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kakocracy)):

> Government under the control of a nation's worst or least-qualified citizens. - [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kakistocracy)

According to [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kakocracy%2Ccidocracy%2Ckakistocracy%2Ccacocracy%2Ccacistocracy%2Cthanatocracy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckakistocracy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccacocracy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthanatocracy%3B%2Cc0), this seems in significantly more common usage than thanatocracy, while cidocracy does not appear at all within the Google books english corpus.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *cidocracy*, as Gibson Burrell has done in his *Pandemonium: Towards a Retro-Organization Theory* (1997):

> In classic Orwellian 'Newspeak', of course, defence means war, the 'Final Solution' meant genocide and '*Lebensraum*' meant the Slavic killing fields. What we really face here in the Square of Pandemonium is 'cidocracy'. Certainly the Enlightenment did not create rule by killers ‒ but it made them much more efficient in waging war.

[Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=3u6r0Uxj7IAC&lpg=PT155&ots=kmxdiKPOkQ&dq=cidocracy&pg=PT155#v=onepage&q=cidocracy&f=false)

This combines *cid-*, to kill, with *-cracy*, rule.

Comment: That's certainly original. It doesn't look good to me, but that's just my opinion. No other word that I know of starts with "cido-" meaning "killer-related," and it violates the usual convention to combine Greek with Greek and Latin with Latin roots (a convention which of course has many existing exceptions, such as "television", "monovalent" etc., but I don't exactly like to see more of them).

Answer (score 0):

Ask it to Heny Kissinger who is dreaming of WW3
or create a new word about "death" = "thanatos" in Greak  such as "thanatocracy"
 which doesn't exist in English, what a pity. French link :
http://skildy.blog.lemonde.fr/2007/08/20/definition-de-la-thanatocratiecroquisdephilo200807/

Comment: Actually [thanatocracy does exist in English](http://www.yourdictionary.com/thanatocracy), however it's most relevant definiton (number 2 in the link) is probably a little too extreme for what I was looking for.